Larave database connection
I am a bit confused about laravel database connection.
If I execute a laravel code that select from database three queries as example.
If laravel establish database connection and login into database then logout for each executing query or laravel connect with the first query and logout after the last query.
// login to the database
    User::all();
// logout from database
// login to the database
    Info::all();
// logout from database
// login to the database
    Family::all();
// logout from database

or
// login to the database
    User::all();
    Info::all();
    Family::all();
// logout from database

I am asking that for database session not on the code level.
All regards

An open connection remains open for an entire request (or when you manually close it)

When you establish a connection (like $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=test', $user, $pass);) and run multiple queries, such as $conn->query('SELECT * FROM table'); and $conn->query('DELETE FROM table');, you are not establishing a new connection for each query. Instead, the connection remains open and gets reused. You can close the connection manually or create a new connection by defining it explicitly (new PDO...).

You forgot to ask a question. Which part of the given snippets confuses you?

Typically, Laravel will establish a DB connection once and reuse that connection for subsequent queries within the same request.
In other words, Laravel keeps the database connection open within the same request.
It doesn’t log in and out for each query.

Laravel establishes a database connection at the beginning of a request if a query needs to be executed and maintains this connection throughout the request. It does not open and close connections for each individual query. The connection is closed automatically when the request is completed.
So This the correct version :
// login to the database
User::all();
Info::all();
Family::all();
// logout from database

